# Use Byte[] was converted from a string and sent through webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I convert a file to a byte array and then I transfer it using a web service. When I receive the byte array, I convert it back to a file.

It's works ok, but the problem is when I convert a string to byte, like this:

`<b>My Content</b>`

and transfer it through the web service, how can I get a file with an HTML format (like doc, docx...) like:

> **My Content**

I can save it as .txt but it's not the result I want. Here is the code I used to save it:

```
public ActionResult Download(byte[] bytes)
{
    return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,"Filename");
}
```

Comment: Do you want a rendered HTML page or are you wanting to turn HTML marked up text in to a doc or docx file? Also i see in your last code snippit you refrence Pdf, how does that play in?

Comment: Yes, I have a string write with HTML code. I turn it into byte[]. Now I want turn the byte[] back to string or anything for saving it as doc or docx file with HTML rendered.
I try PDF but I cant open it. It's said "file is not Pdf format".

Comment: I try Application.Octet, pdf, etc. but it wasn't work. It can be saved but with wrong character. TXT is displayed ok but plain text with HTML code inside.

Comment: You want it (the docx, doc file etc) to look as if it were a webpage ?

Comment: @MohammadYaseen : yes, like that. Do you have some advice for me?
I find the way to save it to doc file but I got new problem that it doesnt show unicode character?